# R error which says "Models were not all fitted to the same size of dataset"

Tags: r, glm, lm, anova

I have created two generalised linear models as follows:

```
glm1 <-glm(Y ~ X1 + X2 + X3, family=binomial(link=logit))

glm2 <-glm(Y ~ X1 + X2, family=binomial(link=logit))
```

I then use the `anova` function:

```
anova(glm2,glm1)
```

but get an error message:

> "Error in anova.glmlist(c(list(object),dotargs), dispersion = dispersion, :
>       models were not all fitted to the same size of dataset"

What does this mean and how can I fix this? I have `attach`ed the dataset at the start of my code so both models are working off of the same dataset.

Comment: On a side note, don't use `attach()`.

Comment: Also, I'm assuming you used `glm(Y~X1...)` and not just `(Y~X1...)`? And why do you have commas separating the variables?

Comment: Yes i used that. Apologies that i did not post it on here correctly before. Any idea what might be wrong?

Comment: Without seeing your data or code, no. Using `attach` could definitely cause that problem.

Comment: Instead of using attach, would i specify the glm as glm(Y ~ X1, X2, X3, family=binomial(link=logit), data.df) for each one?

Comment: you need to use `data=YourData` in the `glm`, and you can't use commas to separate variables like that.

Comment: Yes, again that was a silly error on my part. Using data=YourData worked. Thanks so much :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36047/discussion-between-denis-and-senor-o)

Comment: Also, how do i get the p-value from the anova result? as i only get deviance in the output. thanks again! :)

Comment: I think `anova(glm1,glm2,test="Chisq")` is what you want

Answer (score 21):

The main cause of that error is when there are missing values in one or more of the predictor variables.  In recent versions of R the default action is to omit all rows that have any values missing (the previous default was to produce an error).  So for example if the data frame has 100 rows and there is one missing value in X3 then your model glm1 will be fit to 99 rows of data (dropping the row where X3 is missing), but the glm2 object will be fit to the full 100 rows of data (since it does not use X3, no rows need to be deleted).

So then the `anova` function gives you an error because the 2 models were fit to different datasets (and how do you compute degrees of freedom, etc.).

One solution is to create a new data frame that has only the columns that will be used in at least one of your models and remove all the rows with any missing values (the `na.omit` or `na.exclude` function will make this easy), then fit both models to the same data frame that does not have any missing values.

Other options would be to look at tools for multiple imputation or other ways of dealing with missing data.

Comment: Thanks for that, it was very explanatory. It seems to work when i stopped using attach and chose to specify the data in each glm. Is this only working by chance? Also, I am looking to get a p-value from anova between glm1 and various other glms. How do I do this?

Comment: @Denis, With `attach` you may have had a variable of the same name in the global environment/workspace that was messing things up.  One of the reasons not to use `attach`.  To get a p-value from `anova` add `test="Chisq"`, see `?anova.glm` for details (and make sure that you are happy with the assumptions).

Answer (score 9):

To avoid the `"models were not all fitted to the same size of dataset"` error, you must fit both models on the exact same subset of data. There are two simple ways to do this:

- either use `data=glm1$model` in the 2nd model fit
- or retrieve the correctly subsetted dataset by using `data=na.omit(orig.data[ , all.vars(formula(glm1))])` in the 2nd model fit

Here's a reproducible example using `lm` (for `glm` the same approach should work) and `update`:

```
# 1st approach
# define a convenience wrapper
update_nested <- function(object, formula., ..., evaluate = TRUE){
    update(object = object, formula. = formula., data = object$model, ..., evaluate = evaluate)
}

# prepare data with NAs
data(mtcars)
for(i in 1:ncol(mtcars)) mtcars[i,i] <- NA

xa <- lm(mpg~cyl+disp, mtcars)
xb <- update_nested(xa, .~.-cyl)
anova(xa, xb)
## Analysis of Variance Table
## 
## Model 1: mpg ~ cyl + disp
## Model 2: mpg ~ disp
##   Res.Df    RSS Df Sum of Sq      F  Pr(>F)  
## 1     26 256.91                              
## 2     27 301.32 -1   -44.411 4.4945 0.04371 *
## ---
## Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

# 2nd approach
xc <- update(xa, .~.-cyl, data=na.omit(mtcars[ , all.vars(formula(xa))]))
anova(xa, xc)
## Analysis of Variance Table
## 
## Model 1: mpg ~ cyl + disp
## Model 2: mpg ~ disp
##   Res.Df    RSS Df Sum of Sq      F  Pr(>F)  
## 1     26 256.91                              
## 2     27 301.32 -1   -44.411 4.4945 0.04371 *
## ---
## Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

See also:

- [How to update `lm` or `glm` model on same subset of data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22429122/how-to-update-lm-or-glm-model-on-same-subset-of-data)

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to use:

```
glm1 <-glm(Y ~ X1 + X2 + X3, family = binomial(link = logit), na.action = na.exclude)
glm2 <-glm(Y ~ X1 + X2, family = binomial(link = logit), na.action = na.exclude)

anova(glm2,glm1)
```

This will make R include the cases with missing data (NA) in the fitted model. This ensures that datasets are identical across different fit models no matter how missing data is distributed.

Comment: The `na.exclude` approach won't necessarily work. Try this: `mtcars[1,2] <- NA; xa <- lm(mpg~cyl+disp, mtcars, na.action = na.exclude); xaa <- lm(mpg~disp, mtcars, na.action = na.exclude); anova(xa, xaa)`

Comment: You are right. It doesn't work in this case. It does however ensure that `predict` inserts `NA`s for the datapoints that have missing values in the data. Reading the documentation for `na.exclude` it notes that this only works for `naresid` and `napredict` which are connected to `resid` and `predict`. Apparently, `anova` uses something else.

Apparently, one will have to subset to the complete cases first, e.g. using `na.omit`. At least, that's [the advice given here](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2011-January/266199.html).

Comment: There are at least two straightforward approaches to doing this which I discuss in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18387258/r-error-which-says-models-were-not-all-fitted-to-the-same-size-of-dataset/37416336#37416336).

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you meant to type:

```
glm1 <-glm(Y ~ X1+X2+X3, family=binomial(link=logit))

glm2 <-glm(Y ~ X1 + X2, family=binomial(link=logit))
```

The formula interface for R regression functions does not recognize commas as adding covariates to the RHS of the formula. And don't use `attach()`; use the data argument to regression functions.

Comment: Yes, I have done all of this and the error still seems to come up. I have also inputted: na.omit=na.pass to see would the blank cells in my data by treated differently in R but to no avail. Any idea what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: I would use a `data` argument that was the same for both `glm` calls: na.omit(YourData[ , c("Y" , "X1","X2","X3")])`. That way you remove the "extra cases" that are present for X1 and X2 that are not in X3.

Comment: Do I put this glm1 <-glm(Y ~ X1+X2+X3, family=binomial(link=logit), na.omit(YourData[ , c("Y" , "X1","X2","X3")])) when defining both glms?

Comment: The data argument should be the same and the formulas should be different.

Answer (score 0):

The cause is well described by Greg Snow. An alternative and very easy solution is to add a new variable, matching the problematic variable's NA's and otherwise with the value 1. Include it in both models and R will exclude the same rows in both models (--> datasets will match).

Comment: None of these anwers seem to work in this case:fit4=lm(ctmax~ta+ratectmax,data=x,na.action = na.exclude)# rectilinear
fit5=lme(ctmax~poly(ta,2)+ratectmax,random=~1|col,data=x,na.action = na.exclude)
fit6=lme(ctmax~poly(ta,3)+ratectmax,random=~1|col,data=x,na.action = na.exclude)
fit7=lme(ctmax~poly(ta,4)+ratectmax,random=~1|col,data=x,na.action = na.exclude)
anova(fit4,fit5,fit6,fit7) - it gives the same error, with no missing data.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the easiest way to handle this situation without imputing the missing values is to create a new dataset using tidyr's drop_na() function.

For this function, put all the variables that you'll need in your final model inside the drop_na() portion, and it will remove any rows that have missing values in any relevant variable:

```
library(tidyr) #load in drop_na()

mtcars[1,2] <- NA #makes the first row of the cyl column become NA to illustrate

no_missing <- mtcars %>%
  drop_na(cyl)

glimpse(no_missing) #note, you only have 31 obs instead of 32 now
```

drop_na() also works across multiple columns:

```
library(tidyr)

mtcars[1,2] <- NA #makes the first row of the cyl column become NA to illustrate
mtcars[3,1] <- NA #makes the 3rd row of the mpg column become NA to illustrate

no_missing_2 <- mtcars %>%
  drop_na(mpg, cyl)

glimpse(no_missing_2) #now, you only have 30 obs
```

By running drop_na() with all the variables that you'll be using in your most complex model, you'll ensure that you're using the same dataset.