# Error comparing linear mixed effects models

Tags: r, nan, anova, lme4, mixed-models

I want to see whether the fixed effect `Group2` in my model is significant. The model is:

```
Response ~ Group1 + Group2 + Gender + Age + BMI + (1 | Subject)
```

To check the significance I create a null model not containing the effect `Group2`:

```
Resp.null = lmer(Response~Group1+Gender+Age+BMI+(1|Subject),
    data=mydata,REML=FALSE)
```

and the full model containing the effect `Group2`:

```
Resp.model = lmer(Response~Group1+Group2+Gender+Age+BMI+(1|Subject), 
    data=mydata,REML=FALSE)
```

Then I use `anova()` to compare the two, but I get an error:

```
anova(Resp.null, Resp.model)
## Error in anova.merMod(Resp.null, Resp.model) : 
##   models were not all fitted to the same size of dataset
```

I think that the problem is that `Group1` contains `NaN`, but I thought that linear mixed models were robust to missing data.
How can I solve this problem and compare the two models?

Do I have to delete the rows corresponding to `NaN` and fit `Resp.null` without these rows?

---

The data can be downloaded [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3vXKJ_zYaCJRVRseGVjMDNiRDQ/view?usp=sharing). 
Please note that you should replace `"<undefined>"` with `NaN` like this:

```
mydata = read.csv("mydata.csv")

mydata[mydata == "<undefined>"] <- NA
```

Comment: Could you share a reproducible version of mydata (for example, with `dput(mydata)`)? If it's too large, or too private, see if you can create a subset of the data and reproduce it (e.g. with `dput(head(mydata, 10))`), or reproduce it on public data. Otherwise it's impossible to tell why the function failed in your case

Comment: I added the link to download the data. Thanks!

Comment: Please note that the problem (and the missing values) is in Group2...I edited the question

Comment: Yes, you need to remove the rows of missing values so both models are fit to the same dataset to use `anova.merMod`.  You could create a new data object without the missing values and feed this to both model calls or you can add the subset argument to both models - something like `subset = !is.na(Group1)`.

Comment: Can I use the full model (comprising rows containing NaN) to describe the response or should I always refer to the "submodel"?

Comment: @aosmith you shouldn't need `anova.mermod`. Method dispatch will find the appropriate generic function. The proper call is `anova`.

Comment: @Alex I mention `anova.merMod` specifically because the behavior that the subset/dataset must be identical for the full and reduced model isn't standard for `anova` methods of other objects I commonly use (`anova.lm` and `anova.lme` spring to mind) so this recommendation of using `subset` in both is specific to `anova.merMod`.

Comment: @aosmith this (subset) doesn't matter--see the function definition: `anova <- function (object, ...) {UseMethod("anova")}` If you supply two `merMod` objects to `anova`, method dispatch will find the appropriate generic function (ie- `anova.merMod`). Certainly, you can make the call directly, but it's generally not the preferred practice.

Comment: Using `subset = !is.na(Group1)` or `na.omit(data)` would probably lose cases, as `lmer` imputes missing data and has probably more observations than just the complete case deletion.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid the `"models were not all fitted to the same size of dataset"` error in `anova`, you must fit both models on the exact same subset of data.

There are two simple ways to do this, and while this reproducible example uses `lm` and `update`, for `lmer` objects the same approach should work:

```
# 1st approach
# define a convenience wrapper
update_nested <- function(object, formula., ..., evaluate = TRUE){
    update(object = object, formula. = formula., data = object$model, ..., evaluate = evaluate)
}

# prepare data with NAs
data(mtcars)
for(i in 1:ncol(mtcars)) mtcars[i,i] <- NA

xa <- lm(mpg~cyl+disp, mtcars)
xb <- update_nested(xa, .~.-cyl)
anova(xa, xb)
## Analysis of Variance Table
## 
## Model 1: mpg ~ cyl + disp
## Model 2: mpg ~ disp
##   Res.Df    RSS Df Sum of Sq      F  Pr(>F)  
## 1     26 256.91                              
## 2     27 301.32 -1   -44.411 4.4945 0.04371 *
## ---
## Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

# 2nd approach
xc <- update(xa, .~.-cyl, data=na.omit(mtcars[ , all.vars(formula(xa))]))
anova(xa, xc)
## Analysis of Variance Table
## 
## Model 1: mpg ~ cyl + disp
## Model 2: mpg ~ disp
##   Res.Df    RSS Df Sum of Sq      F  Pr(>F)  
## 1     26 256.91                              
## 2     27 301.32 -1   -44.411 4.4945 0.04371 *
## ---
## Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

If however you're only interested in testing a single variable (e.g. `Group2`), then perhaps the `Anova()` or `linearHypothesis()` in `car` would work as well for this usecase.

See also:

- [How to update `lm` or `glm` model on same subset of data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22429122/how-to-update-lm-or-glm-model-on-same-subset-of-data)
- [R error which says "Models were not all fitted to the same size of dataset"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18387258/r-error-which-says-models-were-not-all-fitted-to-the-same-size-of-dataset/37416336#37416336)

Comment: I think it would be slightly more robust to use `model.frame(object)` in place of `object$model`

Answer (score 0):

Fit `Resp.model` first, then use `Resp.model@frame` as data argument.

```
Resp.null = lmer(Response~Group1+Gender+Age+BMI+(1|Subject),
data=Resp.model@frame,REML=FALSE)
```

Comment: better to use  the accessor method `model.frame(Resp.model)` rather than accessing slots directly ... note (both this answer and the other one) that this approach will fail when the formula involves complex bases (`poly()`, `ns()`, `bs()` or data transformations (`log(x)`)

Comment: @BenBolker Do you mean the `Resp.model@frame` approach or the `model.frame(Resp.model)` approach? And why would it fail in case of say `log(x)` transformations?

Comment: either.  If you have a term `log(x)` in the formula, then the model frame will actually contain a column called `log(x)`.  Then, when `lmer` tries to evaluate the term `log(x)` in the formula in the *new* model, it will try to find an `x` column in the data and will fail.

Comment: Yes, `model.frame` should usually be used, especially when you write your own function or packages. However, for a quick analysis, I sometimes use the way that requires less typing (i.e. fit@frame instead of model.frame(fit)) :-)