# Comparing nested models

Tags: r, nested, models

I am trying to compare two nested models that have different number of participants so I keep getting an error message.

> Error in anova.lmlist(object, ...) :    models were not all fitted to
>   the same size of dataset In addition: Warning message: In
>   anova.lmlist(object, ...) :   models with response ‘"NULL"’ removed
>   because response differs from model 1

- Is there a way of correcting this? The code I'm using is a`nova(fit1, fitall, data=RMS2_working)` `fit1` has 5 predictors and is `df=352`, fitall has 10 predictors and `358 degrees of freedom`

Thank you!

Comment: Please tag this post with the language that you're using

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: The easy way would be to fit your models to the same subset of data.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18387258/r-error-which-says-models-were-not-all-fitted-to-the-same-size-of-dataset