# Anova test regression vs. knn in R

Tags: r, regression, knn, anova

I'm trying to take an anova test for two different models in R: a `lm` model vs. a `knn` model. The problem is this error appears:

`Error in anova.lmlist(object, ...) : models were not all fitted to the same size of dataset`

I think this make sense because I want to know if there are statistical evidences of difference between models. In order to give you a reproducible example, here you have:

```
#Getting dataset
xtra <- read.csv("california.dat", comment.char="@")
names(xtra) <- c("Longitude", "Latitude", "HousingMedianAge",
"TotalRooms", "TotalBedrooms", "Population", "Households",
"MedianIncome", "MedianHouseValue")
n <- length(names(xtra)) - 1
names(xtra)[1:n] <- paste ("X", 1:n, sep="")
names(xtra)[n+1] <- "Y"

#Regression model
reg.model<-lm(Y~.,data=xtra)

#Knn-model
knn.model<-kknn(Y~.,train=xtra,test=xtra,kernel = "optimal")

anova(reg.model,knn.model)
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can get `california.dat` from here: http://sci2s.ugr.es/keel/dataset/data/regression/california.zip

Comment: You'll most likely find your answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18387258/r-error-which-says-models-were-not-all-fitted-to-the-same-size-of-dataset

Comment: Thanks for your response, @AntoniosK, but my dataset has no `NA` values in any column, so, these answer is not useful for me.

Comment: If I `predict`, I get different values from two models, but none of it is `NA`.

Comment: Yes, I checked myself as well and that's why I removed the suggestion. It's definitely not a NA issue here :-)

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that the two models aren't comparable with `anova()` and this error is being thrown because one of the models will be deemed empty.

From the documentation for `anova(object,...)`:

- object - an object containing the results returned by a model fitting
  function (e.g., lm or glm).
- ...  - additional objects of **the same type**.

When you look to see if the models can be compared you can see they're of different types:

```
> class(knn.model)
[1] "kknn"
> class(reg.model)
[1] "lm"
```

Probably more importantly if you try and run `anova()` for `knn.model` you can see that you cannot apply the function to a `kknn` object:

```
> anova(knn.model)

Error in UseMethod("anova") : 
  no applicable method for 'anova' applied to an object of class "kknn"
```

Comment: Well, two models can `predict`, in fact, `knn.model` includes predictions if i get `knn.model$fitted.values`, so, I think it shouldn't be treated as empty. Anyway, the problem could be what you say, `kknn` object is not compatible with `anova()`. So, what you'd do in order to get an statistical (meaningfully similar to anova) comparison?

Comment: What I want to do is simply compare the two models. I can get an SME error from both models in a regression problems. So if I perform cross-validation for two models, I get two different "numbers". I need `anova` in order to check (via p-value) if errors differs statistically, this is, if a model is (statistically) better than the other one.

Comment: @Carlos you can get an error for each prediction (pred - actual). And therefore a squared error. Assuming you predict on a dataset with N rows, you'll get N squared errors for each model. You can use a statistical test to compare those averages (which will be the mean squared error of each model). Like a `t.test`.

Comment: At the end I took Wilcoxon test, that compares two different models, given a p-value. Thanks anyway!